# Finding the discounted net price in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
  rate:<input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" /><br/>
  discount:<input type="text" name="dis" id="dis" /><br/>
  net:<input type="text" name="net" id="net" onClick="sum()"/>
    </body>
```

Here are my three fields named rate,discount and net...Now I am trying that when I enter rate and discount so discount should be deducted from the rate and the price left comes on net textbox.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
  function sum()
                  {
      a=Number(document.getElementById("rate").value);  
  b=Number(document.getElementById("dis").value);

    c=Number(a-b/100);
     document.getElementById("net").value=c;    

     }



   </script>
```

Here is my javascript code.....when I am entering rate=120 and discount=10 so net amount should be 108 but it is showing net=119.9  which is wrong...could anyone help me out

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 function sum()
 {
      a=Number(document.getElementById("rate").value);  
      b=Number(document.getElementById("dis").value);
      c=a-(Number(a)*Number(b)/100);
      document.getElementById("net").value=c;    
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3bRMC/)

Answer (score 0):

The right formula is

```
discount = rate * (dis / 100)
net = rate - discount
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct formula would be -

> discountedRate = actualRate - (actualRate*discount / 100)

In your case it would be

```
c = Number(a) - ( Number(a) * Number(b) / 100);
```